# Running a python node in ROS2 (humble)

Tags: python, nodes, executable, ros

I am trying to run my python node but I have not been successful in sourcing the executable or even locating the node.
[This is the error I keep getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4jMv.png)

I am not sure how else I can be able to source the files. I have tried " source ~/.bashrc" but I am also getting an error there. [My screen is the one on top right and the other one in the background is the tutorial I am following.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5bXz.png)

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial that's telling you to run the executable directly is giving you very bad advice you shouldn't follow.

Once a package has been build you should source the workspaces install directory then run the executable as a ros node *via `rosrun or` roslaunch`*. For you that would look like:

```
source ros2_ws/install/setup.bash
ros2 run my_py_pkg py_node
```